# How can I stop a Xcode simulated gpx route to interfere with the device's current location?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, location, gpx

I am using this tool https://mapstogpx.com/mobiledev.php to generate a gpx file with waypoints in order to simulate a vehicle trip. It works almost perfect except that from time to time the device's real location is being received among the locations from the gpx file.

Has anyone encountered this problem and knows how to solve this?

I am using Xcode 8.3.2 and testing on an iPhone SE with iOS 10.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Options (See image where you should get)

- under this is Core Location -> Default Location - Set this to non and TADA :)

Problem solved.

(If you dont see Core Location under Options you have to run your project first)

[image]